# Why we can't play <audio> via attribute/props?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've been learning ReactJS for a while and it has successfully made me wondering how common HTML elements were built. Then, I met `<audio>` and some other common tags.

From what I read, I felt that the major way for 'doing something' to an HTML element is by adding props/attribute to elements, right? But now why can't we play the audio in a `<audio>` element by writing `play='true'` props/attribute to it? Or maybe `props="play"`?

Instead we have to get the DOM reference to it and invoke functions attached to it?

Is there any reasoning used behind that design?

Comment: HTML is a presentational language, interaction is left to JavaScript

Comment: if you want to autoplay it, just put it " controls autoplay";

Answer (score 0):

the `<audio />` tag doesn't even have the play attribute. React doesnt create non-existing attributes for you, they have to already exist.

these are the existing attributes that audio tags have.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Here are the docs for adding the react attributes
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to auto play a `<audio>` element you have to set the attribute `autoplay="true"`. The property isn't called `play`, `play()`is a method on the `HTMLMediaElement`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/autoplay